# PJAX в Yii2

Tags: pjax, yii2, yii, php

Доброго времени суток. Помогите, пожалуйста побороть проблему. Есть код:

```
<?php
        yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['options' => ['id'=>123, 'timeout'=>3000]]);
        echo ListView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'itemView' => '_message',
            'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}"
        ]);
        yii\widgets\Pjax::end();
        ?>
```

И

```
function updateMessage(){
        $.pjax.reload({container: '#123'});
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(updateMessage, 3000);
    });
```

Но беда в том, что я думал, что PJAX обновляет только определенный кусочек, а всё остальное остаётся нетронутым, однако фокус у формы теряется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы ListView обновлялся,  всё остальное оставалось нетронутым (в том числе и фокус формы).

Comment: как то не стыкуется Но беда в том, что я думал что PJAX обновляет только определенный кусочек, а всё остальное остаётся не тронутым,  И как сделать так чтобы ListView обновлялся, всё остальное оставалось не тронутым.
У вас не тот блок обновляется или что? страничку есть где глянуть?

Comment: В чём суть сайта: это чат, сверху форма ввода, а ниже список сообщений, которые выводятся через ListView, дело в том, что когда обновляется ListView, слетает фокус с поля формы, это напрягает пользователей, не знаю, как исправить. :(

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
 $('idэлемента').focus(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    });
```

UPD

Ну, тогда  я бы сделал так:

```
$('idэлемента').focus();
```

Клавиатура вылетает - нужно копать в ее строну и искать метод, ее закрывающий.

Comment: Уже делал так. С мобильного телефона, это очень неудобно, т.к. постоянно вылазит клавиатура. (

Comment: обновил, погляди

Comment: В этом случае фокус опять пропадает. (

Answer (score 0):

PJAX обновляет часть данных на странице.  Им можно обернуть грид большой, к примеру, и постраничный вывод.

А то что пропадает фокус, тут нужно  передавать обновленный JS скрипт после обновления новых данных.

Все ведь просто.